# Apache Kafka: Exception emitting metrics

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Hortonworks Sandbox HDP 2.4 in Bridge Mode. When I run ./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties in kafka to start Kafka broker, I am getting following error:

```
[2016-06-23 06:45:37,779] ERROR Exception emitting metrics (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.kafka.KafkaTimelineMetricsReporter)        
org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.timeline.UnableToConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused                       
        at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.timeline.AbstractTimelineMetricsSink.emitMetrics(AbstractTimelineMetricsSink.java:87)       
        at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.kafka.KafkaTimelineMetricsReporter.access$200(KafkaTimelineMetricsReporter.java:58)         
        at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.kafka.KafkaTimelineMetricsReporter$TimelineScheduledReporter.report(KafkaTimelineMetricsRepo
rter.java:253)                                                                                    
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused                                                                               
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)                                                                       
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)                                                
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)                                         
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)                                                  
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)                                                                  
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)                                                                                    
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)                                                                     
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)                                                                 
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)                                                                 
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)                                                                     
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)                                                                        
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)                                                                        
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:998)                                    
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:934)                                        
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:852)                                             
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1093)                                    
        at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.timeline.AbstractTimelineMetricsSink.emitMetrics(AbstractTimelineMetricsSink.java:73)       
        ... 11 more                                                               Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused                                                                               
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)                                                                       
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)                                                
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)                                         
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)                                                  
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)                                                                  
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)                                                                                    
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)                                                                     
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)                                                                 
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)                                                                 
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)                                                                     
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)                                                                        
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)                                                                        
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:998)                                    
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:934)                                        
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:852)                                             
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1093)                                    
        at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.timeline.AbstractTimelineMetricsSink.emitMetrics(AbstractTimelineMetricsSink.java:73)       
        ... 11 more
```

Comment: I am getting this error as well. For me, it began when I enabled LDAP authentication and am wondering if that is related? So no solution, but would love to see one.

Comment: Update: I have altered the Kafka property under Advanced kafka-broker of kafka.ganglia.metrics.host from localhost to 0.0.0.0 to allow it to bind to anything. This has made the error stop appearing for now. Admittedly this is not the best long term solution but it seems to be working for me so far.